# Tabularx ignores initial skip in \rowcolors{Skip}{Color1}{Color2}

Tags: tabularx, rowcolor

Here is a MWE with initial skip 3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \rowcolors3{blue!20}{green!20}
  \caption{With tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{*3{p{0.33\columnwidth}}}
    \hline
    Time  & Money   & Length \\
    \hline
    Contemporary \\
    Sec   & \$      & inch   \\
    Hour  & cents   & cm     \\
    \hline
    Ancient \\
    ?     & Dinar   & Yard   \\
    horae & Drachma & Palm   \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
  \caption{With tabularx}
  \rowcolors3{blue!20}{green!20}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{XXX}
    \hline
    Time  & Money   & Length \\
    \hline
    Contemporary \\
    Sec   & \$      & inch   \\
    Hour  & cents   & cm     \\
    \hline
    Ancient \\
    ?     & Dinar   & Yard   \\
    horae & Drachma & Palm   \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Indeed, a duplicate. But, the short answer: *tough luck buddy*, is not so immediate in the original.

Comment: As a work-around, you can add `\rowcolor{white}` at the beginning of the first two rows. B.t.w., you should load `caption` : LaTeX forgets to swap the values of `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` when the caption is placed above the float (as should be for tables), so that the spacing between caption and table is quite petty.

Comment: 10ex. https://www.sharelatex.com/project/589dcdc8959868b11ca2fe07

Comment: Yes, I initially had the same result. What is the problem?